# Sed with wildcard between " "

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have some file in which I need to change the logging level and trying to use sed

```
    <asyncLogger name="blabla" additivity="true" level="info" includeLocation="true">
    </asyncLogger>

    <asyncLogger name="blabla1" additivity="true" level="fine">
```

I tired this command but it cuts down the end of the line.

```
sed  's/\(level="\).*/"\1\debug\"/' file.xml
```

I am trying to fine level="wildcard" and replace it with level="debug" and the rest of the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost never a good idea to modify xml with `sed`...

That said, your issue is the `.*` since it is greedy. It sucks up the remainder of the line.

You can do:

```
$ sed -E 's/(level=")[^"]*/\1debug/' file
<asyncLogger name="blabla" additivity="true" level="debug" includeLocation="true">
</asyncLogger>

<asyncLogger name="blabla1" additivity="true" level="debug">
```

Comment: Works perfectly :) what would you use to modify XML if not sed ?

Comment: Something with a proper xml parser. Python, Perl, Ruby, PHP, Java, Javascript, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the regular expression less greedy as your .* eats everything to the end of the line.

```
sed -r -e 's/(\<level *= *)["a-zA-Z"]+/\1"debug"/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should replace `level="blah"` with `level="debug"`

```
  sed -e 's/level="[^"]"/level="debug"/g' file.xml
```